# How do i set number of tasktrackers per node in a cluster ?

Tags: hadoop

I see that we can set number of map/reduce tasks per tasktracker but how do i set number of tasktrackers per node in a cluster ?

How do i turn off security so that i can run more than one tasktracker per node ? Is it enough to set dfs.permissions to false in hdfs-site.xml ?

Arun

Comment: And what is the need to do so?

Comment: You likely do not want to be doing this...

Comment: @Arun: There is only one TaskTracker per hadoop slave node.

Answer (score 4):

Why would you need multiple tasktrackers? 
You can run multiple jobs depending on the number of slots you set in the tasktracker. The JobTracker talks to the tasktracker to find if it has any free slots on the server (starting with the same node the data is and elsewhere if it can't) If you do have multiple tasktrackers they wouldn't be aware of the real load on the server and the performance is likely to deteriorate

You should set the number of slots, the maximum number of maps and the maximum number of reduces depending on the memory and cpu capabilities of your nodes (you can start with core-per-task but if you know your tasks are low on CPU you can set that higher)

Answer (score 3):

If you have a 8 core machine with single thread model, setting aside 1 thread for datanode, 1 for tasktracker, you can have 6 threads available. Depending on the need of the program, you you may have 4 maps, 2 reducers. If the maps are not CPU intensive, you may increase the number of mappers. Also assign proper memory to each map/reduce task based on the RAM of the system.